# Writing xarray dataset is much slower than reading it?

Tags: python, geospatial, netcdf, python-xarray

I use xarray `open_dataset` to open about 4000 NetCDF files. I like to save the dataset without any processing. While reading the 4000 files takes about a minute (no lazy reading), writing it might take hours. The total size of the directory containing the files is about 750 Mb. Here I compared reading and writing individual files using `xr.open_dataset` vs. `xr.open_mfdataset`:

Reading individual files:

```
ds = xr.open_dataset('path to file')
CPU times: user 7.95 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 7.95 ms
Wall time: 6.95 ms
```

Writing individual files:

```
ds.to_netcdf('path to output')
CPU times: user 76.3 ms, sys: 4.01 ms, total: 80.4 ms
Wall time: 78.4 ms
```

Reading all the files with open_mfdaset:

```
ds_all = xr.open_mfdataset('path to files/*.nc')
CPU times: user 1min 3s, sys: 880 ms, total: 1min 4s
Wall time: 1min 4s
```

Select one of the files:

```
ds_sel = ds_all.isel(time=1)
CPU times: user 20.2 ms, sys: 5 µs, total: 20.2 ms
Wall time: 19.6 ms
```

Writing the selected dataset:

```
ds_sel.to_netcdf('path to output')
CPU times: user 3.89 s, sys: 11.9 ms, total: 3.9 s
Wall time: 3.89 s
```

As you can see writing each file of the dataset takes ~4 seconds meaning that for 4000 files it takes about ~5 hours. Compare this 4 seconds with 78 ms when we write individual files opened with open_dataset.

**I am not sure what I am doing wrong here?**

BTW here is how each file looks like:

[image]

Comment: you aren't reading in any of the data in any of your read tests. `xr.open_datset` *is* lazy by default, and `xr.open_mfdataset` uses dask (which is even more lazy), so even when you've selected the first time slice, you *still* haven't read any data. reading and writing 4000 files will take a while.

Comment: Note that 700 MB is tiny, and spreading this small amount of data across 4000 files means the vast amount of your time is going to be spent scheduling, opening and closing files, loading disparate addresses in memory, etc. I would definitely try to consolidate these by loading them all with mf_dataset and then writing them all to a single file.

Comment: taking a look at your dims it actually looks like the data might be pretty heavily compressed. I get around 23 GB for the size of the full set of three arrays? If that's the case, I'd probably try writing to zarr, which will still compress the data on write but can make use of parallel writes, so you'd be able to use multiple processors to write the data

Comment: Ah! Thanks. For some reason, I thought open_mfdaset used dask only when we set compute=False. I am going to try the loading and zarr. Thanks again.

Comment: bundled this into a more comprehensive answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of reasons why opening datasets in xarray may be faster than writing:

- [`xarray.open_dataset`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/generated/xarray.open_dataset.html#xarray.open_dataset) uses lazy loading with netCDFs. This is the defualt behavior of the NetCDF library (as well as a number of other backends such as zarr) - xarray just exposes it. See the User Guide section on [reading NetCDFs](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/v2022.06.0/user-guide/io.html?highlight=lazy#netcdf):

  > Data is always loaded lazily from netCDF files. You can manipulate, slice and subset Dataset and DataArray objects, and no array values are loaded into memory until you try to perform some sort of actual computation. For an example of how these lazy arrays work, see the [OPeNDAP section](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/v2022.06.0/user-guide/io.html?highlight=lazy#opendap) below.
- `xarray.open_dataset` also caches data by default. From the API documentation:

  > **`cache`** (`bool`, *optional*) – If True, cache data loaded from the underlying datastore in memory as NumPy arrays when accessed to avoid reading from the underlying data- store multiple times. Defaults to True unless you specify the *chunks* argument to use dask, in which case it defaults to False. Does not change the behavior of coordinates corresponding to dimensions, which always load their data from disk into a `pandas.Index`.
- [`xarray.open_mfdataset`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/generated/xarray.open_mfdataset.html#xarray.open_mfdataset) uses dask, meaning that any non-blocking operations you perform, including slicing, most computation, many reshape operations, etc. will only schedule the tasks, not execute them. So if you're not including the execution time in your profiling, you're only capturing the time it takes dask to infer the shapes and types of the arrays involved as well as the time it takes to schedule subsequent operations.

[`xarray.Dataset.to_netcdf`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/latest/generated/xarray.Dataset.to_netcdf.html#xarray.Dataset.to_netcdf) on the other hand *is* a blocking operation, and the compute time will reflect the full time to complete any scheduled dask operations, to load any lazy-loaded data which has not yet been pulled into memory, and to write the full array(s).

Note also that xarray can only write netCDFs in serial, so even if you use dask for your operation, all of your data must flow through the single main thread before it can be written. Zarr is a similar storage format which allows distributed writes, getting around this bottleneck for distributed systems. This is usally less of a concern if you're working on a local machine which is likely constrained by write speeds, but on networked storage or on a cluster this can become a real performance factor.

Comment: Thanks, just a question. So, if we only want to load a series of files using open_mfdataset and save them to disk, to my understanding the to_netcdf reflects the time to load the data and save them to disk. So, if I read my 4000 files lazily using open_mfdaset then use the .load method to load them on disk and then save them, it takes a few minutes which is much less than reading the data and saving them to the disk without explicitly using the .load method. Why is that? I thought the to_netcdf does the same thing (i.e. load the data).

Comment: sorry - I'm having a hard time understanding the exact comparison you're making without seeing the code. can you include it or ask another question?

Comment: Sorry I frame the question poorly. The problem is solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The lazy loading behavoir of xarrays described above was the issue for me, using `xr.open_mfdataset(files).load()` fixed this issue for me.

This took my write time down from hours to a couple minutes for seperate files of 2918 daily precipitation files into one big one of 900mb.